# Why do I see youtube ads from channels I have blocked?

Tags: youtube, youtube-channel, google-feedback

I do not pay for the youtube service that blocks ads, so I do not have the expectation of not seeing ads. That said, I expect to stop seeing ads from channels that I have blocked.

Since I do not like Apple, I blocked their channel. Despite this, I see Apple ads when scrolling through my feed. I have tried down-voting these ads and reporting them. I have even tried the “send feedback” option of youtube. Clearly, all responses are automated and my feedback has not been read - this has been going on for months.

How can I stop seeing ads from channels that I have blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Blocking someone on YouTube will stop them from interacting with you, ie comment on your videos. It doesn't affect other things.

To block certain ads, you can click on the (i) next to the "time remaining" thing in the bottom left corner and then click on "stop seeing this ad".

You'll also see who the advertiser is targeting when you click on the (i). If you have personalized ads, you can use that information to change the types of topic you want to see advertised.

More is in the help center:

- [Block certain ads](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2662922)
- [Control the ads you see](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2662856)

Comment: I have tried clicking the "stop seeing this ad" tab. Usually, a pop-up is opened, asking which of the three given reasons account for why I don't want to see the ad. The problem with this is that I am doing this over and over again for the same advertisements. So, this does not work. 

Secondly, I have already tried changing the settings for personalizing ads to my account. I have turned "ad personalization" on and off - neither affect ads from certain companies. Suppose I like tech but hate Apple - guess I'm SOL...

Comment: "To block certain ads, you can click on the (i) next to the "time remaining" thing in the bottom left corner and then click on "stop seeing this ad"." Unfortunately that is just for show, it doesn't actually do anything and you still get the ads you've blocked.